# how to repeat a code on user input?

Tags: javascript

I want to repeat the code until the user gets the no. right. How do I do this ?
This is the code:-

```
function getRandomNumber(min,max){
     return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max - min + 1 ))+min;
 }
 randomNumber=(getRandomNumber(1,10));

 input=prompt("Please enter a no. between 1 and 10:","");
 if(input==randomNumber){
     console.log("Good Work");
 }else{
     console.log("not matched");
 }
```

Comment: a `while` loop and a `break` could help

Comment: Any time you find yourself using the word "until" to describe program flow, it means you need to use a `while` loop or a recursive call.

Comment: `console.log` doesn't return anything. Assign `randomNumber` directly to the value returned by `getRandomNumber`.

Answer (score 0):

You could either use a while loop that calls a "break" statement once the user inputs the correct answer, or you could use a function like this:

```
function getInput(){
 input=prompt("Please enter a no. between 1 and 10:","");
 if(input==randomNumber){
     console.log("Good Work");
 }else{
     consol.log("not matched");
     getInput(); //Gets the user's input again
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go...

Found needs to be set to false before you start, otherwise the function will only run one.  There is little point having the function definition inside the while loop, since it will be created as a global variable.

```js
var found = false;

function getRandomNumber(min,max) { return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max - min + 1 ))+min; }

while ( found != true ) { 
  
  var randomNumber = getRandomNumber(1,10);

 console.log('Random Number is..',randomNumber);

  var input = prompt("Please enter a no. between 1 and 10:","");
 
  if ( input == randomNumber ) {
      alert('Well Done')
      found = true;
  } else {
      console.log("not matched");
  } 
}
```